# Elasticsearch - Required terms in a Lucene Query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am working on a search query against an Elasticsearch search index. Sometimes, I want to require that a term be present. To address this scenario, I've been reading about the "+" [boolean operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators). However, I'm slightly confused by it.

I do not understand where it fits against the AND (&&) operator and using the phrase operator ("). For example, lets say I had a search index of animals. Imagine I wanted to find foxes. How is

`brown +fox` different from `brown && fox` different from `"brown" && "fox"`. In my understanding, these are very similar. I understand how the last two differ. However, for the life of me, I do not understand why I would ever use the "+" operator.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for the life of me, I do not understand why I would ever use the "+"
>   operator.

`+` : this term must be present

`-` : this term must not be present

All other terms are optional. For example, this query:

```
quick brown +fox -news
```

states that:

- `fox` must be present
- `news` must not be present
- `quick` and `brown` are optional — their presence increases the relevance

**Phrase Query :**

`Phrase`, surrounded by double quotes —

```
"quick brown"
```

— searches for all the words in the phrase, in the same order

`AND` and `&&` are both the same operators i.e. both must be present.

I hope it clarifies.

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators)